# Yii2 MaskedInput widget with spesial characters

Tags: input, yii2, masking

I need to create input for company name. It can be from 1-4 words and use "". Now I can just make like this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),['name' => 'name',  'mask' => ['[A][a]{1,10}[ ][a]{1,10}[ ][a]{1,10}[ ][a]{1,10}']]) ?>
```

But right now I can use just letters. I see there is `$definitions` in this widget  but how to use it correct?

After trying some othr options, I make it like this:

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),['name' => 'name',     'mask' => '"[A]a"',
                    'definitions' => [
                        'a' => [
                            'validator' =>  '^[А-ЯЁA-Z]+',
                            'cardinality' => 50,
                        ]
                    ]]) ?>
```

But I need to be dynamic length of this definitions. So now in my field

```
"Asddasdsa asdnmsadas d asdasd asdsamj______________"
```

And I need it to make dynamic length so the " symbol was after text

Comment: If you are allowing special characters, then what is the point in use of masked input. Simply use textfield with length validation

Comment: There should be first capital letter, @Nitin

Comment: You can manage this at backend, using php function like `ucfirst()`. In MaskedInput you can add `mask` option which will allow you, **alpha character, numeric character and alphanumeric character only**. So better to go with `textfield` and `ucfirst()`

Comment: @Nitin I need it to be shown when typing name

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the first letter in uppercase while typing then use JQuery function as follows

```
$("#your-field-id").keyup(
     function () {
         this.value = this.value.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.value.substr(1).toLowerCase();
     }
 );
```

Comment: I need to use my mask because there is quotes also